# Transparent vs. white panel with light background

Tags: desktop, themes, release-juno

Folks; using a bright background in elementary 5, I see a strange behaviour with the top panel background. In *some* cases, with no window opened, the panel is completely transparent and the icons top-right seem right "on the background". However, "often" (like ever third or fourth boot), the panel background will turn way opaque, see screenshot. I don't see a pattern in here and I don't know how to make the panel *always* transparent in this setup whenever no window is opened. Any recommendations on that? Any idea what's wrong here?
TIA and all the best,
Kristian

[image: opaque white panel] -- this is not how I want it.

[image: transparent white panel] -- this is how it should be but just occassionally is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communicating within the elementaryos Slack channel, it seems a reported / known bug. See https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/184# for more.